# How to connect to VPN of type L2TP programatically in ios8

Tags: ios8, frameworks, vpn, l2tp

I have a mobile configuration file and the `VPNTYPE` is `L2TP`. How can I connect to this vpn programatically ? Can I use `NETWORK/EXTENSION` framework for this? There are only 2 protocol classes - `NEVPNProtocolIPSec` and `NEVPNProtocolIKEv2`.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use SDK 8 NetworkExtension.framework to connect to L2TP.
It can be used for IPSec with IKEv1 and IKEv2 only.